# How to draw a line based on giving bearing/heading value at current location in iOS/swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been doing a ton of research but found nothing. With MapKit, I have got a map that shows current location and elsewhere a function that calculates a heading/bearing value (not necessarily the actual heading). How can I draw a line on the map that will start at current location, and point in direction of the given heading ? (Does not matter how long the line is, as in it has no meaningful end point). I am not asking you to write the code for me but would appreciate some detailed direction. Hope this helps others too.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinates are [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), which means you have a direction and a length. You just need to convert them to Cartesian, which gives you a horizontal offset and a vertical offset. You do that with a little trigonometry.

```
let origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
let heading: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi
let length: CGFloat = 20

let endpoint = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(heading)*length,
                       y: origin.y + sin(heading)*length)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: origin)
path.addLine(to: endpoint)
```

Note that trigonometric functions generally work in radians (2*PI = one revolution). Bearings are often in degrees (360 degrees = one revolution). Converting is straightforward, however:

```
func radians(forDegrees angle: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.pi * angle / 180.0
}
```

Comment: Great. Presumably this would work with long/lat coords ? Sorry! I'm no good at trig.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to convert them to map points. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968477/mkmappoint-with-mkmappointmake-from-mkmaprect for a more complete example of that.

Comment: Another question: as i currently have long and lat doubles, will i have to convert to map point for this formulae, then convert back to long/lat for MKPolyline drawing ?

Comment: That is probably the most straightforward since all the conversion tools are available in map kit. It's of course possible to do all the calculations in spherical coordinates, but if Cartesian trig is uncomfortable, then spherical trig is probably going to be even more confusing.

Comment: Cheers - i decided to go with a full formulae that takes in long / lat. thanks for direction.